# QGIS Print layout: Making a Slider to create a number value

Tags: qgis, print-composer

We currently have a QGIS template to deliver to a client,the thing is we are locking some items to make sure they are not edited. However some things like the Attachment number need to edited. Of course in theory you can adjust put an expression in a label, just like we are doing with the project number and project name. The thing is because the attachment number is always a number we were more interested in putting in a slider like item into the layout, like you have in the QGIS Forms if you define a range of numbers.

Is this possible or not? And if yes, how do I do this?

Edit: Ok so it is possible using this code more or less to get a slider in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}
.serif {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
p
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 17px;
}

p.impact {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <p class="impact"> Bijlage nummer:  <span id="demo"></span></p>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  </div>

  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    
    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
**The problem the slider is not interative in this HTML Frame, when I click on it I can only move the frame itself.** **How do I make it interactive?**

Comment: You could try this using html, e.g. following this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

Comment: This is nice but So I can techincally use the html but then how do I used the CSS portion.

Comment: There's a sub-menu to add a user style sheet.

Comment: Never mind Ingore my last omment I have it fully Incorparted the problem I still cannot interact with except my moving the frame itself. This will not do.